# cocoa - disable java software update?

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an objective-c app that seems to trigger the built-in software update to install java if it's not yet installed.

This is probably caused by me checking /usr/bin/java -version? (I do this via a NSTask in objective-c)

See this code snippet:

```
- (NSString *)getJavaPath
{
NSArray *possiblePaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/usr/bin/java", @"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java", nil];

for (NSString* possiblePath in possiblePaths) {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:possiblePath]) {
        continue;
    }

    @try {

        NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath:possiblePath];

        [task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-version", nil]];

        //apparently java version is outputted to standard error..?

        NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
        [task setStandardError: pipe];

        NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

        [task launch];

        NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

        [task waitUntilExit];

        NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if ([text rangeOfString:@"1.7"].location != NSNotFound) {
            return possiblePath;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return nil;
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

Could it be that this code triggers the built-in java software update?

I do not want this popup to appear since I'm installing my own java version if the JDK is not 1.7.

Is this possible via objective-c (disabling the alert)?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - because I'm using it? I check the java version via a NSTask. That's probably what triggers it, or not? I just need to disable that apple popup.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - I have edited my question with extra objective-c information, please remove the off-topic status.